# Does a scroll of remove curse uncurse rings and amulets?

Tags: nethack

The [wiki page](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Scroll_of_remove_curse) for the scroll of remove curse says

> The scroll of remove curse, when read, will uncurse **worn or wielded items**, loadstones and leashes in use.

(emphasis mine)

Does that only include items that I have actually <kbd>w</kbd>ielded or <kbd>W</kbd>orn, or does it also include rings or amulets that I have <kbd>P</kbd>ut on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we consult [this guide](http://www.steelypips.org/nethack/341/scrl-341.html#remove_curse), we can infer that:

- An *uncursed remove curse scroll* uncurses everything equipped to you (<kbd>W</kbd>orn or <kbd>P</kbd>ut), but not inventory items. However, if you <kbd>w</kbd>ield an inventory item and read uncursed remove curse scroll, that item gets uncursed like as if it was equipped gear.
- A *blessed remove curse scroll* uncurses everything you're carrying, unless it's inside a container, in which case it isn't affected (not in main inventory).
- A *cursed remove curse scroll* does nothing (unless you're punished, in which case it unpunishes you, thus applies to to id you are using an uncursed or blessed remove curse scroll as well).

Comment: You know, you didn't say anything that is not in my question. I really want to know whether they meant "worn" in the formal sense of armor or the informal sense of things attached to your body. Also, wear is a capital W.

Comment: Its been a while since I've played this game, but I made some changes. I hope you find them satisfactory.

Comment: The guide you linked to actually says the opposite of what you said: It includes amulets, rings, and eyewear in the list of things that the scroll effects.

Comment: The scroll *affects* items that you [P]ut on, too. I've added this detail.

Comment: In short, yes the scroll of remove curse does remove the curse on rings and amulets.

Comment: "as if it was equipped gear" is a silly phrasing; if you wield an object it *is* equipped gear.